# Unable to load data set from JSON file

Tags: java, json, junit, jboss-arquillian

I have an abstract class person and inherit the class employed. I am doing unit tests with a json file but when I run the test I get the following error org.jboss.arquillian.persistence.dbunit.exception.DBUnitInitializationException: Unable to load data set from given file: employed.json What am I doing wrong?

Class Person

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.Long;
import java.lang.String;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Person implements Serializable {  

@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false, 
length = 11)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, updatable = true, length = 50)
private String name;

@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, updatable = true, length = 30)
private String email;

@Column(name = "phone", nullable = false, updatable = true, length = 16)
private String phone;

@Column(name = "password", unique = false, nullable = false, updatable = true, length = 20)
private String password;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Person() {
    super();
} 
}
```

Class Employed

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
public class Employed extends Person implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Employed() {
    super();
}
}
```

Test

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.jboss.arquillian.transaction.api.annotation.TransactionMode;
import org.jboss.arquillian.transaction.api.annotation.Transactional;
import org.jboss.arquillian.persistence.UsingDataSet;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class EmployedTest {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {
return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class,
"test.war").addPackage(Employed.class.getPackage())
.addAsResource("persistenceForTest.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
.addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
}

@Test
@Transactional(value=TransactionMode.ROLLBACK)
@UsingDataSet({"employed.json"})
public void findTest() {
    Employed employed = entityManager.find(Employed.class,123456L);
    Assert.assertEquals("pete",employed.getName());
}
}
```

and JSON File

```
{
"employed":
[
    {
        "id":123456,
        "name":"pete",
        "email":"pete@gmail.com",
        "phone":"3233934933",
        "password":"123456"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Where is your `employed.json` located? Can you share the whole stacktrace?